# How do I set the options for CMAKE_AR?

Tags: cmake

I'm doing cross compiling with CMake and all is OK but the **CMAKE_AR** options.

I use `set(CMAKE_AR ${GCC_PATH}/dld)` to set **CMAKE_AR**. But I don't know how to set its option. By default, it uses the options *rc* to create the archive. But I need to change it to be `-X -r5 -o`. When use *rc*, it will complain the file *rc* cannot be found.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I filed a feature request at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19474

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the flags "crs" are hardcoded in the command for creating an archive. There's no way to override just the flags; you have to rewrite the whole command, like this:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -X -r5 -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -X -r5 -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

There's also a `CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_APPEND` (and CXX equivalent) used when the number of objects exceeds the command line maximum, it passes just the "r" flag to CMAKE_AR. You may have to change that one too, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_ARCHIVE_CREATE.html

Comment: Thanks. It wrks. And I found those commands must be placed after the project(xxx) command.

Comment: If I has a so to append to target archive, what option(<????>) should I append after <OBJECTS> ? Where is the reference of <TARGET>,<LINK_FLAGS> and <OBJECTS>?