# CMake: include library dependencies in a static library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building a **static** library in CMake, which is dependent on many other static libraries. I would like them all to be included in the output .lib/.a file, so I can just ship a big lib file to customers. In Visual Studio 2010 there is an option, *"Link Library Dependencies"*, which does exactly this.

But I can't find how to do it in CMake. Can you set this flag via CMake, or get the same result some other way? I have tried target_link_libraries(...) and also add_dependencies(...), but CMake seems to simply ignore this line for static libraries.

Comment: Do you have static versions of the libraries that need to be linked against? Or do you only have shared versions?

Comment: So when you say it's not including them in your static, is it trying to link your static library against the other shared libraries?

Comment: i have only static libraries, and i only try to build a static library, so no linking is taking place. The problem comes when a third part want to use my libs and have to link to lots of other stuff as well

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, so I have a solution. First it's important to recognize that static libraries do not link other static libraries into the code. A combined library must be created, which on Linux can be done with `ar`. See *[Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)* for more info there.

Consider two source files:

#### test1.c:

```
 int hi()
 {
   return 0;
 }
```

#### test2.c:

```
int bye()
{
  return 1;
}
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is to create two libraries and then create a combined library looks like:

```
project(test)

    add_library(lib1 STATIC test1.c)
    add_library(lib2 STATIC test2.c)

    add_custom_target(combined ALL
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_AR} rc libcombined.a $<TARGET_FILE:lib1> $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>)
```

The options to the `ar` command are platform-dependent in this case, although the `CMAKE_AR` variable is platform-independent. I will poke around to see if there is a more general way to do this, but this approach will work on systems that use `ar`.

---

Based on *[How do I set the options for CMAKE_AR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659225/how-do-i-set-the-options-for-cmake-ar)*, it looks like the better way to do this would be:

```
add_custom_target(combined ALL
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE} libcombined.a $<TARGET_FILE:lib1> $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>)
```

This should be platform-independent, because this is the command structure used to create archives internally by CMake. Provided of course the only options you want to pass to your archive command are `rc` as these are hardwired into CMake for the `ar` command.

Comment: Thanks, the corresponding way to do it on Windows is to add a custom command "lib.exe /OUT:combined.lib 1.lib 2.lib"

Comment: After using this for a bit, I have noticed the "ar" command is very sketchy and produces combined libs that doesn't work in at least some versions of gcc. I think we are just better of not trying to link statically this way.

Comment: For me only the add_custom_target command as described first worked.

Comment: To make it truly platform-independent, the filename needs to be the following: `${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}combined${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}`

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to enhance the other solutions by providing my `CMakeLists.txt` file that actually works also in terms of building dependencies.

**Solution misusing CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_library(lib1 test1.cpp)
add_library(lib2 test2.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR})
add_executable(mainexec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainexec combinedLib)  # Important to place before add_custom_target

set(LIBNAME "combinedLib.lib")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${LIBNAME}
    COMMAND lib.exe /OUT:${LIBNAME} $<TARGET_FILE:lib1> $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>
    DEPENDS lib1 lib2
    COMMENT "Combining libs..."
)

add_custom_target(combinedLib
    DEPENDS ${LIBNAME}
)
```

Note that this solution works so far with Visual Studio but I guess it can be made multi-platform compliant. I can imagine that the following version might work for Unix-based platforms:

```
set(LIBNAME "libCombinedLib.a")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${LIBNAME}
    COMMAND ar -rcT ${LIBNAME} $<TARGET_FILE:lib1> $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>
    DEPENDS lib1 lib2
    COMMENT "Combining libs..."
)
```

Note that these solutions somehow misuse CMake as it would complain about a target of type UTILITY (instead of STATIC or SHARED) if you place the `target_link_libraries` call after the `add_custom_target` declaration.

**CMake target-declaration-compliant solution**

To make it CMake compliant, you can replace the `target_link_libraries' call by

```
target_link_libraries(mainexec ${LIBNAME})
add_dependencies(mainexec combinedLib)
```

In my case it is not entirely satisfactory because `mainexec` has to know about `combinedLib` although it expects all dependencies to be handled by the `target_link_libraries` call.

**Alternative solution with less coupling**

Looking a bit further towards imported targets I eventually found a solution that solves my last problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_library(lib1 test1.cpp)
add_library(lib2 test2.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR})
add_executable(mainexec main.cpp)

set(LIBNAME "combinedLib.lib")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${LIBNAME}
    COMMAND lib.exe /OUT:${LIBNAME} $<TARGET_FILE:lib1> $<TARGET_FILE:lib2>
    DEPENDS lib1 lib2
    COMMENT "Combining libs..."
)

add_custom_target(combinedLibGenerator
    DEPENDS ${LIBNAME}
)

add_library(combinedLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET combinedLib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIBNAME})
add_dependencies(combinedLib combinedLibGenerator)

target_link_libraries(mainexec combinedLib)
```

If you intend to modularize the whole add `GLOBAL` after `STATIC IMPORTED` to make the imported target globally visible.

**Portable CMake solution**

With the current CMake versions CMake provides full support for transitive dependencies and interface libraries. An interface library can then "link" against other libraries and this interface library can, in turn, be "linked" against. Why quotation marks? While this works good, this actually doesn't create a physical, combined library but rather creates a kind of an alias to the set of "sub-libs". Still this was the solution we eventually needed, which is why I wanted to add it here.

```
add_library(combinedLib INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(combinedLib INTERFACE lib1 lib2)

target_link_libraries(mainexec combinedLib)
```

That's it!