# "Hiding" transitive external dependencies / combining libraries with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

This question may be partly duplicate, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake), but is more about what if any are better solutions. Since this question ended up rather long, I marked ***specific questions*** with "***+Q+***" in bold italic.

I have the situation that I wrote a small library `B` that depends on some other huge project `A` split into many libraries `A1, A2, ..., An`, some of which my library depends on and some on which it doesn't. It was a bit of a pain to do the proper linking. The library is starting to be used by others and I would like to avoid everyone having to go through this awful linking process, i.e. I want to compile all the external libraries of `A` into my `B`. Assume `A` is completely external, i.e. that ***I have no way to recompile*** `A` (in this case I do, but it is complicated and I would like to know options for the case that I don't).

I imagine this must be a very standard thing to do, I have used other popular libraries and never did I have to link all the other libraries that they transitively depend on .. ? So I started looking for solutions, and while I found working ones, most solutions seem like a big mess and I wonder if this is really done in practice or if there is some idiomatic way for this.

To avoid more eventual headaches if I ever need a different case, I want to consider all combinations of static/shared libraries, i.e.

- A & B are static
- A is static, B is shared
- A is shared, B is static
- A & B are shared

To give some MWE of the code setup (the variables `LIB1_ROOT` and `LIB2_ROOT` in the **CMakeLists.txt** files are **A/** and **B/** respectively):

**A/include/lib1.hh**

```
struct Lib1 { void run() const; };
```

**A/src/lib1.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lib1.hh>
void Lib1::run() const { std::cout << "Hello from lib1\n"; }
```

**A/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(A)
include_directories(include)
add_library(lib1 src/lib1.cc)
install(TARGETS lib1 DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
```

**B/include/lib2.hh**

```
class Lib2 {
    class Implementation;
    Implementation* impl;
public:
    Lib2();
    ~Lib2();
    void run() const;
};
```

**B/src/lib2.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lib1.hh>
#include <lib2.hh>
class Lib2::Implementation {
    const Lib1 m_lib1{};
public:
    void run() const { std::cout << "using lib1 from lib2: "; m_lib1.run(); }
};
Lib2::Lib2() : impl{new Implementation} {}
Lib2::~Lib2() { delete impl; };
void Lib2::run() const { impl->run(); }
```

**App/src/app.cc**

```
#include <lib2.hh>
int main() { Lib2 l; l.run(); }
```

**App/CMakeLists.cc**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(App)
include_directories(include "${LIB2_ROOT}/include")
find_library(LIB2 lib2 "${LIB2_ROOT}/lib")
add_executable(app src/main.cc)
target_link_libraries(app "${LIB2}")
install(TARGETS app DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

I used the pImpl pattern for `B` since what is the point of hiding link dependencies when I then make the user of my library dig out all the headers anyway.

---

Finally **B/CMakeLists.txt** (for my library) depends on the cases I mentioned above:

### A & B static

**B/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(B)
include_directories(include "${LIB1_ROOT}/include")
find_library(LIB1 lib1 "${LIB1_ROOT}/lib")
add_library(lib2_dependent src/lib2.cc)
add_custom_target(lib2 ALL
    COMMAND ar -x "${LIB1}"
    COMMAND ar -x "$<TARGET_FILE:lib2_dependent>"
    COMMAND ar -qcs "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}lib2${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}" *.o
    COMMAND rm *.o
    DEPENDS lib2_dependent
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
)
```

This solution is from the question I linked at the start. There was also an in my opinion much better version in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022318/using-cmake-to-build-a-static-library-of-static-libraries) using

```
ar -M <<EOM
    CREATE lib2.a
    ADDLIB lib1.a
    ADDLIB lib2_dependent.a
    SAVE
    END
EOM
```

but I could not get to work the here-document inside CMakeLists.txt ... ? There was an additional answer providing what I think was a CMake function to do this, but it was a huge block of code which I found a bit ridiculous for something that *should* be simple / standard practice / integrated into CMake ?
The custom_target solution I wrote here also works, but as mentioned in other answers as well, it unpacks object files which lie around and have to be removed again, for each library I want to compile this way.
And still in both cases, I can only wonder what is the point of using CMake then if I have to use ar manually anyhow. ***+Q+ Is there no better / CMake-integrated way to "compile-in" transitive dependencies / combine static libraries?***

---

### A static, B shared

As far as I found in this case, I'm out of luck if I cannot recomple `A` and it is not compiled as position independent code. The next best thing to make it work was to do just that by adding `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")` to **A/CMakeLists.txt**. Again, there seemed to be better alternatives: `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` or `set_property(TARGET lib1 PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199708/cmake-include-library-dependencies-in-a-static-library), which were complete ignored in my case .. (compiling with `VERBOSE=1`, there was no `-fPIC` flag to be seen anywhere and `B` did not compile)

The **B/CMakeLists.txt** was easy in this case

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(B)
include_directories(include "${LIB1_ROOT}/include")
find_library(LIB1 lib1 "${LIB1_ROOT}/lib")
add_library(lib2 SHARED src/lib2.cc)
target_link_libraries(lib2 "${LIB1}")
install(TARGETS lib2 DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
```

and while I don't find anything wrong with this solution, according to answers I found I should need to set additional flags like `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--export-all-symbols")` in order for the symbols in the static library to be found. However the above works just fine, compiles, and `App` runs without issues? **+Q+ Am I doing anything wrong here?** Or is it maybe due to some update to CMake since these older answers?

---

### A shared, B static or both shared

According to what I found here, this is basically impossible, because shared libraries are "final" in some sense. I find this very strange, surely there are many libraries that do not require a project that uses them to link every single dependency of that library that happens to be a shared library? ***+Q+ Are there really no options in these cases?***

Comment: Remove all `LIB2_ROOT` `LIB1_ROOT` and use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to reference current directory where `CMakeLists.txt` is in. I think your post is close to being too broad.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not sure I understand. How would I e.g. refer to `A/include/lib1.hh` from `B/CMakeLists.txt` (which is a different project!) without having some sort of input variable or hard-coding (obviously bad) the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you're doing wrong :)

The CMake-way is to use [packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages). Once you've made the `LibA` package, you just do `find_package(LibA)` in your `B/CMakeLists.txt` and also the generated `LibBConfig.cmake` (the package config file, so your clients would need just `find_package(libB)` in their `App/CMakeLists.txt`) ought to find (that is questionable IMHO, but currently its CMake way) its dependency the same way (using or not the CMake's helper [`find_dependency`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html)).

The whole process gets much simpler that way:

- you have/give the full control on how to build (including what version, library type static/dynamic, &etc) and where to install the `libA` on your developer's host and customer's machine (so dependent projects could find it)
- same for `libB` and `App`
- you and any customer of your library(ies) use the well known CMake way to find dependencies and have full control over this process
- and the most important **let CMake do complicated things instead of you** that keeps your build logic much simpler in `CMakeLists.txt` of all involved projects