# CMake: CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE usage

Tags: c++, cmake, archive

Im using

```
add_custom_target(combined ALL
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE} 
    ${PROJECT_NAME}Full${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} 
    $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> ${LIB_A} ${LIB_B})
```

as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200728/4434064.

The variable ${CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE} is defined as

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qc <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

The resulting Makefile states:

```
"<CMAKE_AR> qc <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>" ProjectFull.a Project.a LibA.a LibB.a
```

The variables CMAKE_AR, TARGET, ... will not be replaced by CMake and "make combined" is not executable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` Well, you are wrongly expecting them to be replaced. They will not be replaced. The are replaced when cmake creates a static library, not in a custom target. Is it a XY question? What do you want to do? Do you want to combine multiple static libraries together?

Comment: Yes, I want to combine multiple static libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake)

Comment: @KamilCuk no it does not, as it limits the solution to UNIX-like systems, and using CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE seems like a cross-platform way. 
Why are they not replaced? What if the custom target is intending to create a static library?

Comment: `Why are they not replaced?` It's hard to reason why something does not happen. It doesn't happen because it's not meant to happen. There is nothing that would "replace" `<these_parts>` for anything else inside `add_custom_target` command. `What if the custom target is intending to create a static library?` Then _you_ need to write a command yourself.