# cmake override archive command when building assembly source library w/ IAR toolchain

Tags: cmake, iar

I'm attempting to build a static library with the IAR toolchain using cmake. I'm building only assembly files in this library (which I think is an important detail here), and they build fine. When it gets to the archiving step, however, I can see that its invoking the archiver with "GNU" style arguments.

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 6.5/arm/bin/iarchive.exe" cr libasm.a  "somefile.s.obj" "someotherfile.s.obj"
```

Instead of 'cr' it needs to be '--create'

How does cmake determine the make up of this command and how can I specify what it needs to be for my toolchain?

My abridged cmake script for this library looks like this

```
enable_language(ASM)
add_library(asm ${ASM_SOURCES})
target_compile_options(asm PUBLIC ${ASM_COMPILE_FLAGS})
target_include_directories(asm PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I am able to build some C/C++ archives in the same script with no issues. I've tried manually setting the CMAKE_AR in a few different spots and it doesn't work. Again, I'm building **ONLY** assembly files in this archive, so I'm not sure if that's why its not using those archive commands.

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> --create -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> --create -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>"
```

I've tried running this on cmake versions 3.4.0 and 3.4.1.

Comment: Which version of CMake? Tried the newest one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the options for CMAKE\_AR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659225/how-to-set-the-options-for-cmake-ar)

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting `CMAKE_ASM_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY` replaced the command being invoked.

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> <TARGET> --create <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> ")
```

I chose the makeup of the command based on the CXX archive command found [in IAR-CXX.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/IAR-CXX.cmake)

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> <TARGET> --create <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> ")
```